# Cannot modify a default parameter group for remaining connection slots on Amazon RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, laravel-vapor

I keep getting:

> SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL: remaining connection slots are reserved
> for non-replication superuser connections (SQL: select * from "sheeps"
> where "name" = foobar limit 1)

So I thought of modifying the value in the paramaeter group (max_connections default on 270)

But when I change the max_connections to a higher value, I get:

> "Error saving: Cannot modify a default parameter group. (Service:
> AmazonRDS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue;
> Request ID: b5179a68-xxxx-44a8-b396-xxx; Proxy: null)"

I have the max limit Laravel Vapor offers: 3008 mb.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can't modify the default parameter group in AWS RDS.

You need to create a custom parameter group, set `max_connections` in that group, and then attach it to your PostgreSQL RDS instance. You'll then need to restart your PostgreSQL RDS instance for the change to take effect.

Comment: Sounds great, but how can I do that?

Comment: See this guide: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-modify-parameter-group-values/

Comment: too bad.. "Incompatible-parameters" when setting it to 10000

Comment: See "Maximum number of database connections" on this page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Limits.html

Comment: Nowadays you need to first create a custom parameter group and then assign to the database. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithParamGroups.html#USER_WorkingWithParamGroups.Creating